# How to get inputTextArea value into another bean?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to get the value with the getter method, but it doesn't work. I use SessionScoped into my two managed-beans.

```
<h:outputLabel for="commentInput" value="Comment:" />  
<p:inputTextarea id="commentInput" value="#{dashboardBean.currentComment}" rows="6" cols="25" label="commentInput" required="true"/>

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class DashboardBean implements Serializable 
{
    private String _currentComment = null;

    public String getCurrentComment() {
       return this._currentComment;
    }

    public void setCurrentComment(String _currentComment) {
       this._currentComment = _currentComment;
    }
}
```

If i call getter in this class, it's works.

But in the other class:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class PanelListener extends AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl
{
    private DashboardBean _dashDashboardBean = null;

    public void editMemo(ActionEvent actionEvent)
    {
      System.out.println("Statements ==== [ " + _dashDashboardBean.getCurrentComment() + " ]");
    }
}
```

I have an NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `@ManagedProperty` annotation to inject one bean into another.

```
@ManagedProperty("#{dashboardBean}")
private DashboardBean bean;

public DashboardBean getBean(){
   return this.bean;
}
public void setBean(DashboardBean bean){
   this.bean = bean;
}
```

Make sure the scope of the `ManagedProperty` is greater than or equal to the scope of bean in which you are injecting.

so here, `DashBoardBean` should have scope greater than or equal to `PanelListener`

Please note that JSF needs `public` getters and setters to access the fields

Comment: I added ManagedProperty and setter method has PanelListener, my beans are both in SessionScoped but I have this error:"SEVERE: JSF will be unable to create managed bean panelListener when it is requested.  The following problems where found:
- Property _dashDashboardBean for managed bean panelListener does not exist.  Check that appropriate getter and/or setter methods exist."

Comment: You need to add the getter and setter methods for bean variable. I've edited the answer accordingly .

Comment: Yes i know, i try that. I added getter/setter to my class PanelListener, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: It's works, my problem was the name of my variable '\_dashboardBean'! Don't put underscore '_' at the beginning of a variable. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `@ManagedProperty` annotation. So try this in PanelListener, note that you need a setter to perform the bean injection. You can also only inject beana with greater or same scope to the bean with lower scopes (so for example you can inject SessionScoped to the RequestScoped but not the other way around).

```
 @ManagedProperty("#{dashboardBean}")
 private DashboardBean bean;

 private void setDashboardBean(DashboardBean bean) {
     this.bean = bean;
 }
```